# In excel how do I extract domain name from email address, match with another column and flag a match in another

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have to extract domain name from email address (like `test@bigplace.com`) - I need `"bigplace"` to match with another column (company name `"BigPlace"`) and flag a match or not in another column.

I have tried and tried but I can't get it to work.
Please help me!

[image]

Comment: If you want to extract then use `FILTERXML()` function or `SUBSTITUTE/REPT/RIGHT` function combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this in your Match Column

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH("\*"&B2&"\*",A2,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
=NOT(ISERROR(FIND(UPPER(B1),UPPER(A1))>0))
```

Explanation:

- Apparently in one column you are using small letters, in the other there might be capitals. By capitalising everything, you create a case-insensitive search.
- The result of a `FIND()` either is a location (a number) or a `#VALUE` error. Using `Not(IsError(... > 0))` is a neat trick to change the format `Number/#Value` into `TRUE/FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

Another aproach is;

```
=IF(UPPER(B2)=UPPER(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"@","*",LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"@",""))))),IF(RIGHT(A2,4)=".com",".com",IF(RIGHT(A2,4)=".edu",".edu",IF(RIGHT(A2,4)=".gov",".gov",IF(RIGHT(A2,4)=".int",".int",IF(RIGHT(A2,4)=".org",".org",IF(RIGHT(A2,4)=".net",".net",IF(RIGHT(A2,3)=".co",".co",IF(RIGHT(A2,3)=".us",".us",IF(RIGHT(A2,7)=".com.tr",".com.tr",IF(RIGHT(A2,4)=".mil",".mil",2)))))))))),"",1)),"True","False")
```

This way it'll automatically detects ".com";".edu";".int";".gov";".org";".net";".co";".us";".mil";".com.tr" domains. Another domain can be added after this part

> ".mil",2

as IF(RIGHT(A2,4)=".bla",".bla",2)   and dont forget to increment "4" for ".newdo" as "6" (number of characters)